# Can we convert a simplex tableau into a linear program?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

Say we have been given a simplex tableau and let us assume that this isn't the first tableau (i.e. simplex has been run once or twice on it at this point). Can we convert this tableau back into the form of a linear program that will have the same optimal value as the one we've started with? I've attatched a tableau below so that we can discuss the same tableau.

[image]

Comment: The rows of the tableau are just shorthand for equations. Is that the part that's giving you trouble?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes that was the point I was finding tricky. I think I have figured it out now though. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, all the variables on the left-hand side are basic, and the value they take is the corresponding value on the right.